# Displaying regression summary table with stargazer()

Tags: html, r, regression, summary, stargazer

I wanted to add a table of the regression summary to my html final document with the stargazer() function however I do not understand why it keeps displaying a text format table . Can someone help me please ?

```
stargazer::stargazer(reg1 , title = "Arrests per capita  VS Video games revenue per capita" , type = "latex",keep.stat = c("n","rsq","adj.rsq","f"))
```

Comment: LaTex code is output as text and you need to pass it to a program capable of producing graphics commants suitable for your chosen output device. If you look at the help page for stargazer, you should see that type can also be "html".

Comment: even when I do type="html" I does not give a table when I knit my document : stargazer::stargazer(reg1 , title = "Arrests per capita  VS Video games revenue per capita" , type = "html",keep.stat = c("n","rsq","adj.rsq","f"),align=TRUE,out = "html")

Comment: You have not offered an example that can be used to debug your difficulties. No one can tell _how_ you are using the output. If you just type the code above into an R session then you will see output to the screen but nothing else will "happen". But I'm hoping you are not just doing that. But there's no way to tell without seeing what document you might be working on and how you are making your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you produce your code in an html format, like markdown. I suggest using `gtsummary` like that:

````
---
title: "Regression"
author: "Author"
output: html_document
---

## Model 

```{r model}
model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + wt, data=mtcars)
```

## Summary 

```{r summary, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(gtsummary)
tbl_regression(model)
```
````

[image]